# Is there a way to store the progress of a code in order to debug more efficiently?

Tags: python, debugging, coding-efficiency

My code consists of two parts:

1. part: Scraping content from a webpage
2. part: Evaluating the content

In the 1st part everything is running without any problems. This part takes about 5min.

But I get errors in the 2nd part. Every time I rerun the code to check whether I succeeded in solving the problem in the 2nd part I have to wait 5min. Is there a more efficient way of debugging?

Is there a way to store a variable from the 1st part of session 1 and reuse it in session 2? I want to skip the 1st part and go directly to the 2nd part.

Comment: Its common to decouple programs using intermediate storage. Part 1 could write its scrape results to a file or database and Part 2 could consume that data. How you save it depends on your data. Perhaps an easy way to to it is to pickle each scrape result to a file named by current time so that it can be processed in order later.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "scrape" you could save entire web pages to files instead of pickling anything.